# How can I create a table in Android, where a cell has reference to another table in my database?

Tags: android, database, one-to-many

As the title suggests, and preferably using Room, how can I create a table where some cells hold a reference to multiple rows in another table, such as below?

[image]

Comment: this is explained completely in https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many - you would have a Contacts class, a Numbers class and a ContactsWithNumbers class with the corresponding DAO

Comment: @Christian thank you for pointing it out, I will have a thorough look, and hopefully find some example implementation too

Comment: @Christian Last thing - when using Room, am I meant to create Repository and ViewModel classes on top of Dao class for each child entity?